# dotnet core get application url in IHostedService

Tags: url, .net-core

My requirement is to send an email with a button that return the user to the application at the right place.

The email is sent by a background job.

The background job check if an object exist in a table and if there is any object, it will send email for each of them.

My main problem is to retrieve the  'http://my-app-domaine.com'  part, because the other part is static to all the environment.

I would like to retrieve that part of the url without being in a controller.

Is it possible ?
Everything i find is about the HttpContext and UrlHelper which i doesn't have acccess.

Comment: You can save the domain url on first request to your api in some singleton class, inject it in your hosted service and then retrieve it there. Everything depends on how your job service works. Anyway you will need to share this data using some additional class.